# MySQL update column based on count from complex join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count, sql-update

I am working to build a report with a rather complex database schema. I have the following tables (simplified for brevity).

```
Table: search_data
------------------------------------------
id   partNumber    clei         searchDate
------------------------------------------
1    NT9X          null         2017-10-15 
2    NT9X          ENBYAAAAAA   2017-11-11 
3    null          ENBYAAAAAA   2017-11-12 
4    NT9X          null         2017-11-15 
5    NNTM          null         2017-11-15 
------------------------------------------

Table: analytics
--------------------------------------------
id   partNumber   clei          num_searches
--------------------------------------------
1    NT9X         ENBYAAAAAA    0
2    EFGH         EEEFFHI       0
3    NT9X         null          0
4    null         ENBYAAAAAA    0
```

Parts have 2 identifiers: partNumber and CLEI

So this would be the same part:
- CLEI: **ENBYAAAAAA**
- Part Number: **NT9X**

Searches go into the *search_data* table, and users can search via partNumber, CLEI, or both. So for the part listed above, you can see in *search_data* that the part has been searched for 4 times (ids 1, 2, 3, and 4).

I need to update the *analytics* table's *num_searches* column with the number of searches for that Part Number **OR** CLEI.

So after updating, the *analytics* table should look like:

```
--------------------------------------------
id   partNumber   clei          num_searches
--------------------------------------------
1    NT9X         ENBYAAAAAA    4
2    EFGH         EEEFFHI       0
3    NT9X         null          4
4    null         ENBYAAAAAA    4
```

I created a join for this that works.

```
SELECT *
FROM analytics_data a
join search_data s
on 
case when a.partNumber is not null and a.partNumber != '' THEN a.partNumber = s.partNumber END
OR
case when a.clei is not null and a.clei != '' THEN a.clei = s.clei END
```

I used the CASE statements to account for the fact that there may or may not be both partNumber and CLEI in either table. A simple a.clei = s.clei statement when clei is NULL in analytics would give me every row with a NULL clei in searches, regardless of partNumber.

This dilemma is what's making the update difficult. I came up with this update statement. I'm not sure if it works or not because it won't finish. I killed it after several minutes, as that's not an acceptable runtime.

```
update analytics a
  set a.num_searches = 
  (
    select count(*) from search_data s where
      (case when a.partNumber is not null and a.partNumber != '' 
       THEN a.partNumber = s.partNumber END
    OR
       case when a.clei is not null and a.clei != '' THEN a.clei = 
        s.clei END)
  )
```

I'm not sure where to go from here. It seems like a simple task, but I'm tired of banging my head on my desk.

Any ideas?

========================================================================

## **Additional details to address Nick's proposed solution.**

My concern is that that are a multitude of iterations for these parts. A part can have a base code like "NT9X", plus a variety of family codes (2 characters), plus another variety of feature codes (2 more characters).

So we could have

```
NT9X
NT9XAB
NT9XBB
NT9XABAA
NT9XABBB
```

and so on. All are the same general part, but with slightly different features. There are also lots of Part Number/CLEI combinations. The same Part Number can have several CLEI codes, and vice versa.

As a result, we are forced to do a lot of **LIKE** queries. If I wanted to get all of the quotes on part NT9X, I have a query like...

```
SELECT * FROM part_quotes WHERE partNumber LIKE 'NT9X%';
```

It works fine for 1 part. But for instances like now, where I have a list of 6000+ parts, and I need data from a dozen different tables to generate a report, it's just impossible to do with a single query.

So with your scenario, I would have to do a **LIKE** query on the part_numbers table to get all of the potential part matches. Then, I would have to use an **IN** clause in table joins on part_id.

Without testing that out, I don't know if it would be more or less efficient.

I have a lot of tables that store information on parts. Tables like...

```
vendor_quotes
internal_quotes
search_results
search_data
sales_history
repair_pricing
pricing
purchase_history
expenses
```

And a lot more. Trying to build a report where I have to make wildcard searches on so many tables and aggregate data is quite a headache. I definitely need a better way to do it, and will test out your solution in the near future.

Comment: I don't fully get your results.  Where do the "4"s come from?  I think the results should be 4, 0, 3, 2.

Comment: The 4's are because **PN: NT9X** and **CLEI: ENBYAAAAAA** are the same part. Any search search for either of those counts both ways. ENBYAAAAAA is a search for NT9X, and a search for NT9X is a search for ENBYAAAAAA.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems too complicated, but I think it should work.  This version is simper:

```
update analytics a
  set a.num_searches = (select count(*)
                        from search_data s
                        where a.partNumber = s.partNumber or
                              a.clei = s.clei
                       );
```

Your data has no blanks, so there is no reason to check for them.

But, as you noticed, performance is pretty bad.  Instead, let's do this in two parts.  Where the part numbers are the same and then where the `clei` doesn't match the part number:

```
update analytics a
  set a.num_searches = ((select count(*)
                         from search_data s
                         where a.partNumber <=> s.partNumber 
                        ) +
                        (select count(*)
                         from search_data s
                         where not a.partNumber <=> s.partNumber and
                               a.clei = s.clei
                        )
                       );
```

This version should be able to take advantage of indexes on `search_data(partNumber, clei)` and `search_data(clei, partNumber)`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to give OPs desired result [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2b62ef/1)

Comment: Actually, I have run it on my Dev system, and some spot checking seems to indicate that it is working. That 2nd index seems to have made it extremely fast, as well. I already had the (partNumber, clei) index. I didn't realize that having the reverse (clei, partNumber) would make a difference, but it really did.

Comment: @scott80109 . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted the answer?

Comment: Further testing shows that this works in most cases, but doesn't work if partNumber is NULL. Unfortunately, this solution does not solve the problem presented.

Comment: You can see the Fiddle here - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b8775/1/0v - it shows that missing partNumber does not give the correct count of 4.

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic argument for proper normalisation of databases. If you had a table `part_numbers` like this:

```
CREATE TABLE part_numbers 
    (id INT, `partNumber` VARCHAR(4), `clei` VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO part_numbers VALUES
    (1, 'NT9X', 'ENBYAAAAAA'),
    (2, 'EFGH', 'EEEFFHI');

SELECT * FROM part_numbers

id  partNumber  clei
1   NT9X        ENBYAAAAAA
2   EFGH        EEEFFHI
3   NNTM        EGFEDGF
```

And you replaced the `partNumber` and `clei` fields in `search_data` and `analytics` with a field `part_id` which referenced `id` in `part_numbers` so for example `search_data` would look like this:

```
id  part_id     searchDate
1   1           2017-10-15
2   1           2017-11-11
3   1           2017-11-12
4   1           2017-11-15
5   3           2017-11-15
```

Then your update query would simply be:

```
UPDATE analytics a
   SET num_searches = (SELECT COUNT(s.id) FROM search_data s WHERE s.part_id = a.part_id)
```

This [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8372b2/3) shows you how you can convert your tables to make your life easier.

Assuming you can't (or don't want to) change your table structure, life gets a lot more difficult. You can produce the table that analytics should look like with this query ([SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fe7a1c/1)):

```
SELECT a.id, a.partnumber, a.clei, COUNT(s.id) AS num_searches
FROM analytics a
LEFT JOIN analytics a2 
ON a.partnumber = a2.partnumber OR a.clei = a2.clei
LEFT JOIN search_data s
ON s.partnumber = a2.partnumber OR s.clei = a2.clei
WHERE a2.partnumber IS NOT NULL AND a2.clei IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY a.id
```

Output:

```
id  partnumber  clei        num_searches
1   NT9X        ENBYAAAAAA  4
2   EFGH        EEEFFHI     0
3   NT9X        (null)      4
4   (null)      ENBYAAAAAA  4
```

And so the update query becomes (note we had to `JOIN` a subquery as we can't use a subquery containing the update table in a `SET` clause) ([SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/78a18c/1)):

```
UPDATE analytics a4 JOIN (SELECT a.id AS id, COUNT(s.id) AS num_searches
FROM analytics a
LEFT JOIN analytics a2 
ON a.partnumber = a2.partnumber OR a.clei = a2.clei
LEFT JOIN search_data s
ON s.partnumber = a2.partnumber OR s.clei = a2.clei
WHERE a2.partnumber IS NOT NULL AND a2.clei IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY a.id) AS c
SET a4.num_searches = c.num_searches
WHERE a4.id = c.id

SELECT * FROM analytics
```

Output:

```
id  partnumber  clei        num_searches
1   NT9X        ENBYAAAAAA  4
2   EFGH        EEEFFHI     0
3   NT9X        (null)      4
4   (null)      ENBYAAAAAA  4
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed comments. i agree that it should be better, and have plans to redesign the DB in the coming months. Your idea is one I'm considering.  But it's complex. Please see my addendum to my question above for more detailed information.